# Loop for a Case

Tags: vhdl

How can I generate a single multiplexer with FOR loop.
Here is a snippet what I mean:

```
CASE test IS
    FOR i IN ... LOOP
        WHEN i => ... ;
    END LOOP;
END CASE;
```

I am aware that one can put FOR before CASE but in that case it will generate many multiplexers?

Comment: The question would be clearer if you said what you are going to put after the `when i =>`. It's possible this isn't really the structure you want.

Comment: I disagree. I intentionally wrote it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a loop like that to generate the expressions for a case statement.  You can probably do something close to what you want without the case, however, by just using the for loop:

```
FOR i IN ... LOOP
  IF test = i then
    output <= myarray(i);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

...but if all you're doing is a simple multiplexer like the above, you don't need the case **or** the loop, you can just index directly with your selection signal:

```
output <= myarray(to_integer(test));
```

Comment: I think that I can use the first snippet. I always connected IF with priority decoders not multiplexers (but that is the case when there is elsif and else statements).

Comment: I just figured out that it will be hard to use IF when you want to cover whole spectrum of values. When test is std_logic you need to have "when others"; or "if ... else { }".

Comment: If you provide a bit more detail regarding exactly what you want to do, instead of listing a broken bit of VHDL and asking "why can't I do this", you might get a better answer!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
CASE test IS
  WHEN i to j => ...;
END CASE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that is not the Case that I wanted.